# Separate Date and Text from a pandas column into new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
col1     col2     text           col4
1        a1       12/07/2023     a2
2        a1       abc            a2
3        a1       12/06/2022     a2
4        a1       def            a2
5        a1       fgh            a2     
6        a1                      a2     
7        a1       xxx            a2
```

Now I want my resultant dataframe to look like this:

```
col1     col2     text       date           col4
1        a1       abc        12/07/2023     a2
2        a1       def        12/06/2022     a2
3        a1       fgh        12/06/2022     a2
4        a1       xxx                       a2
```

The logic is that if there is a date that immediately precedes a text that should be recorded correspondingly to that text. if after a date there are multiple texts, all such texts should be added corresponding to that dates. And lastly, if there is a blank that precedes are text, that means that there was no date and hence a blank should be recorded corresponding to that text as show above (last row)

The critical logic is that the we only have to look at just the immediate date if it's present or not.

How can I achieve this python?

Comment: What is happening with `col1`? What happens to the original values of `2, 4, 5` and `7`?

Comment: that is just an id value. it doesn't matter if these value change during this transformation.

Comment: what happens if the first row starts with a text?

Comment: The first row can either start with a blank or with a date but never with a text as this is how the data was collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as mask for the valid dates and `ffill`:

```
s = (pd.to_datetime(df['text'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
       .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
       .mask(df['text'].eq(''), '')
    )

out = df.assign(date=s.ffill()).loc[s.isna()]
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 text col4        date
1     2   a1  abc   a2  12/07/2023
3     4   a1  def   a2  12/06/2022
4     5   a1  fgh   a2  12/06/2022
6     7   a1  xxx   a2
```